# What does "das wäre aber nicht nötig gewesen" mean?

Tags: phrase, politeness

As a thank you for the people hosting a party I brought them a little present. They said:

> *"Danke schön! Das wäre aber nicht nötig gewesen."*

Shouldn't I have given them anything? Did I do something else wrong?

Comment: Danke, das war bitter nötig!

Comment: In Swabian: Des het's aber et 'braucht!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a phrase to express gratitude. It is an indirect acknowledgment that you intended the gift as a gift, and not for satisfying a perceived necessity ("nötig" comes from "Not", English "need" or "poverty").

The confusion probably comes from the literal translation "That was not necessary / unnecessary", which, as I understand it, is a defensive remark to an attack or insult of sorts.

Edit: The more idiomatic translation and English equivalent is probably "Oh, you didn't **have** to!", in a positive meaning.

Comment: Good answer. I'd like to add that people often use this phrase even if they did expect you to bring a present.

Comment: btw: The "correct" answer to "das wäre doch nicht nötig gewesen" is something along the lines of "aber das ist doch nur eine Kleinigkeit" or "nicht der Rede wert".

Comment: The mentioned defensive remark to an attack or insult would be "das war [jetzt] [aber] unnötig" in German.

Comment: @Stefan: +1 Right! Who says Germans can't be Japanese :-)

Answer (score 7):

It's just a polite phrase meant to convey that you in no way expected to receive a gift, frequently used even by people who did in fact expect one, but want to appear polite. The English equivalent is "Oh, you shouldn't have!"